# Problem with viewing a text file on UIWebview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I have a problem when loading a text file with unicode content into a UIWebview.

How can I set Encoding for the UIWebview using loadRequest like this:

> [myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest
>   requestWithURL:[NSURL
>   fileURLWithPath:tempFilePath]]];

This code seem to work but I can't use it to open MS Office file:

> [myWebView loadData:[NSData
>   dataWithContentsOfFile:tempFilePath]
>   MIMEType:self._mimetype
>   textEncodingName:@"UTF-8"
>   baseURL:nil];

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Are you getting an error? How big is a 'large' file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the value of `self._mimetype`?

Based on this [Technote](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2008/qa1630.html), I do not believe you will be able to open `.docx` (zipped-XML) files, but you should be able to open `.doc` files.

Also make sure that you are using the correct MIME type in the latter case ([`application/msword`](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/)).

Comment: Thanks for helping. I can load 2007 docs now. Need to defined correct extension for the tempFilePath. And everything will work